# Determining 64-bit or 32-bit Haskell installed on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, haskell

Can anyone tell me how to determine if I am using 64-bit or 32-bit Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC) on OS X? I have installed both 32 and 64-bit versions, and I don't know which one `current` is pointing to.

```
⚡ pwd
/Library/Haskell   
⚡ ll
bin -> current/bin
current -> ghc-7.4.2
doc -> current/doc
ghc-7.0.3 
ghc-7.4.2
```

Furthermore...

```
⚡ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.2
```

... does not contain the information I am after.

Incidentally, I am running OS X Version 10.7.5 on an Intel Core i5, so I can run either, [but I am trying to get yesod going](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart)...

> There is a bug in the 64-bit GHC 7.4 for Mac which prevents yesod devel from working  correctly. This bug has been corrected in 7.6. However, as 7.4 is still the recommended platform for development, it is advisable to install the 32-bit version of GHC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `ghc --info`, which should list the target architecture.

A more general-purpose solution would be to chase down symlinks and scripts to the actual GHC binary, and then run `file` on it.

Comment: Yeah, nice one [@shachaf](http://stackoverflow.com/users/712548/shachaf). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

ghci and then type maxBound :: Int

Answer (score 0):

1) I would have thought "compiler --version" would have told you.  I'm surprised that "ghc --version" doesn't :(

2) Another option might be to try the built-in Haskell "showVersion" - that might tell you.

3) A "sure thing" is to use the *nix" "file" command:

`file ghc`
<= This should definitely tell you if ghc is a 32-bit or 64-bit executable

Comment: Unfortunately that only tells you that GHC is a shell script (over here, at least). You have to read the script and work out where the actual executable is (in my case, `/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.1/ghc`).